# How to make horizontal UIStackView wrap height content with UIImageView as its children?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following horizontal `UIStackView`

1. Yellow background
2. Leading, top and trailing same as safe area
3. Alignment = Top
4. Distribution = Fill Proportionally

---

### UILabel as children

If I add `UILabel` as its children, it will automatically wrap height content as below

[image]

---

### UIImage as children

I replace `UILabel` with 3 identical `UIImageView`.

Every `UIImageView` has the following properties

1. Content mode = Aspect Fit

It looks as following

[image]

I was wondering, how can I make the horizontal `UIStackView` wrap to its height content?

I expect the `UIStackView`'s will wrap the `UIImageView`'s content height. As an outcome, we will not observe any yellow background of `UIStackView`.

May I know, how can I achieve so?

So far, I have tried to play around with

1. Content hugging priority of both UIStackView and UIImageView
2. Content compression resistance priority for both UIStackView and UIImageView

Still not able to achieve my desired outcome.

---

The following is the original image source, which is 606x404

[image]

Comment: The runtime simulator behaves same as view editor of xcode.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng - will **every** image be `606 x 404`? Or do you want 3 equal-width "sections" with each imageView set to `Aspect Fit`? Or, do you want 3 variable-width "sections" with each image the same height, but different widths?

Comment: My final goal is to achieve the following - https://i.imgur.com/98JjT6U.png In Android, after perform weight calculation, I can tell the LinearLayout (aka StackView) that I want 10% width for 1st image, 50% width for 2nd image and 40% width for 3rd image. The image height will adjusted based on weight & aspect ratio. The LinearLayout will then wrap its height automatically to wrap adjusted image height. Right now, I try to start with the simplest case (all 3 identical images), but getting stuck.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari No. This definitely can be achieved. As, for the above simple case, for a screen with width 428, we need to scale each image to 142.667 x 95.111. Then, it can fully fill the width and respect the original image aspect ratio.

Comment: From your posted demo screenshots and explanation, I can't see clearly how your suggested way work. My expected outcome is as follow - https://i.imgur.com/t9CxDIk.png All your posted screenshot only consist of 1 kitty instead of 3 kittens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot get this result with only Storyboard setup -- you will need some code.

Based on your image showing your desired output, you want each "row" to:

- have 3 images
- show them at original aspect-ratio
- small spacing between images (such as 4-pts)
- fit so the widths and heights maintain the ratios

First comment - forget `Distribution = Fill Proportionally` on the stack views.

For this layout, the stack view should be:

- `Axis: Horizontal`
- `Alignment: Fill`
- `Distribution: Fill`
- `Spacing: 4`

So, what we need to do is constrain each imageView's aspect ratio based on its image's aspect ratio (height / width).

Here is a full example... it uses these 6 images:

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

We'll also embed the horizontal stack view(s) in a vertical stack view, using the same settings (expect `Axis: Vertical`).

```
class AdjustStackViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var vStack = UIStackView()
    
    var picNames: [String] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // six images, named "p1" - "p6"
        for i in 1...6 {
            picNames.append("p\(i)")
        }
        
        // vertical stack view
        vStack.axis = .vertical
        vStack.spacing = 4
        
        // use auto-layout
        vStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        // add it to the view
        view.addSubview(vStack)
        
        // respect safe-area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // constrain vStack
            //  Top + 20
            //  Leading and Trailing 0
            vStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            vStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            vStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
        ])
        
        fillStacks()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // re-fill images in new (shuffled) order
        fillStacks()
    }
    
    func fillStacks() -> Void {
        
        // remove existing horizontal stack views (if needed)
        vStack.arrangedSubviews.forEach { v in
            v.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        
        let shuffledImages = picNames.shuffled()

        // two horizontal stack views each with 3 images
        var picNum: Int = 0
        for _ in 1...2 {
            let hStack = UIStackView()
            hStack.spacing = 4
            vStack.addArrangedSubview(hStack)
            for _ in 1...3 {
                // make sure we can load the images
                guard let img = UIImage(named: shuffledImages[picNum]) else {
                    fatalError("Could not load images!")
                }
                // create Image View
                let imgView = UIImageView()
                // set the image
                imgView.image = img
                // proportional constraint based on image dimensions
                imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor, multiplier: img.size.height / img.size.width).isActive = true
                // add to hStack
                hStack.addArrangedSubview(imgView)
                // increment pic number
                picNum += 1
            }
        }

    }
    
}
```

Here's how it looks:

[image]

When you run this, each time you tap the view it will shuffle the order of the images, so you can see how the layout adapts.

Comment: Providing relative constraint to ImageView is a very nice technique. I always thought when working with "Distribution = Fill", I need to work with hugging/ compression. Dealing with "Distribution = Fill Proportionally", I need to override the child view intrinsicContentSize. Now I learn something new. Thank you.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng - as I mentioned, ***forget `Distribution = Fill Proportionally` on the stack views***. It *rarely* does what you expect, and really gets wonky if the stack view has `Spacing` not equal to Zero.